# How to check if sbt test failed?

Tags: bash, sbt

I want to write a script that builds, test and deploy my app to test environment. I can run test manully using sbt:

```
sbt test
```

but it doesn't seem to return any value (just raw string test results).

Is there any better method to check if sbt test failed than my current solution:

```
TESTS_FAILED=`sbt test | grep "sbt.TestsFailedException" | wc -l`
```

?

Comment: What is output when sbt test failed? `sbt test; echo $?`

Comment: @Cyrus standard junit test output plus summary:  

    `[error] Failed: Total 36, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 35
    [error] Failed tests:
    [error]  package.MyClassTest
    [error] (test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
    [error] Total time: 15 s, completed May 14, 2015 11:04:22 AM`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Mac OS X, when `sbt test` fails it returns 1 when it succeeds it returns 0. This seems to be exactly what you need.

Note that what you have captures the standard output of the `sbt test` command, which is not exactly what you need. In bash, the return code of a command is captured in the special variable `$?`.

```
sbt test
rc=$?; if [[ $rc != 0 ]]; then exit $rc; fi
```